# Have main website hosted on 3rd party while keeping Google Sites for Users

Tags: g-suite

I want a third party hosting my main site with PHP, MySQL, etc...

I don't know which DNS records to modify.

Is it possible to have the following mappings:

www.example.com      => 3rd party hosting
blog.example.com     => other 3rd party hosting
mail.example.com     => Google Mail
docs.example.com     => Google Docs
sites.example.com    => Google Sites
sites.example.com/internal-site => Google Sites internal site
...

Right now in TotalDNS, I have www => ghs.google.com.
If I modify only this record to point to the IP provided by the 3rd party hosting, is it going to work ? Do I also need to add NameServers, remove the ones Google added ?

Thx for the help

---

current setup

**A records**

@ --> 255.255.255.255

**CNAME records**

www   --> ghs.google.com
docs  --> ghs.google.com
sites --> ghs.google.com

**Name servers**

@ --> ns57.domaincontrol.com
@ --> ns58.domaincontrol.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. you should remove record www=>ghs.google.com
2. add new www=> to hosting provider

that's it

Comment: plus add a MX entry to point to google's smtp server.

Comment: thx that was easy  .... all that was necessary was removing the CNAME record 'www' and insert a new A record 'www' pointing to the IP of my hosting provider.